# Deleting old directory

Tags: shell-script, directory, date, rm

I am trying to add a way to remove backups older than 3 days ago in my script.

See below a stripped down simplified version, which just leaves the removal part.

It was my understanding that `${BACKUP_DEST[$i]}/$OLDBACKUP` should be outputting something like '/Users/christopherdavies/Desktop/rsync/test1.co.uk/07-06-18'.

However, each time this runs, it deletes the folder above, of 'test1.co.uk', and regardless if it 3 days old or not.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction? I haven't been able to make any headway... fresh pair of eyes?

```
#!/bin/sh

WEBSITE_HOST=(
    "test1@shell.gridhost.co.uk"
    "test2@shell.gridhost.co.uk"  
)

BACKUP_DEST=(
    "/Users/christopherdavies/Desktop/rsync/test1.co.uk"
    "/Users/christopherdavies/Desktop/rsync/test2.co.uk"
)

OLDBACKUP=`date -d "3 days ago" +"%d%m%Y"`

SITE_COUNT=${#WEBSITE_HOST[@]}

for (( i = 0; i < SITE_COUNT; i++ )); do

    # Remove old backups    
    if [ -d "${BACKUP_DEST[$i]}/$OLDBACKUP" ]; then rm -Rf ${BACKUP_DEST[$i]}/$OLDBACKUP; fi

done
exit 0
```

Comment: Use [tmpreaper](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/tmpreaper)

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot rely on the file modification date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `date` utility on macOS (which I presume you're using judging from the location of the user home directories) is not GNU `date` and therefore does not support all its features.

This means that you `OLD_BACKUP` variable will be empty (and you ought to see an error message when `date` is run), which in turn means that it's the `${BACKUP_DEST[$i]}` directory that gets deleted.

Instead, you may use `date -v -3d +'%d-%m-%Y'`.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

backup_dest=(
    '/Users/christopherdavies/Desktop/rsync/test1.co.uk'
    '/Users/christopherdavies/Desktop/rsync/test2.co.uk'
)

when=$( date -v -3d +'%d-%m-%Y' )

for backup in "${backup_dest[@]}"; do
    [ -d "$backup/$when" ] && rm -Rf "$backup/$when"
done
```

Alternatively, install GNU coreutils and use GNU `date`.

Other changes made to your code:

- Removed `exit 0` from the end and added `set -e`.  If the script fails, you will want to be able to notice it.
- The website array was not used.
- Loop over the items in the array rather than using indexes, it's easier to read.
- If you want a single line simple `if` statement, you may use short circuit syntax instead (which is shorter).
- Use lower-case variable names.
- Always quote variable expansions.
- It's a `bash` script, so it should reference `bash` on the `#!`-line.

Comment: Thank you! That was the issue. 
Also, thank you for your advice on my script. I am new to bash and still learning (as I am sure my code shows clearly). 
I have added my full script into my question, as I am unsure if some of your points would be correct (for example, removal of some variables etc). 
If you could take a look and let me know, that would be fantastic. I am still working on a way to loop the database connection details...

Comment: @ccdavies I'm happy to have helped.  Rather than continuing to review your code in this answer, I'd suggest that you ask a new question if you have specific issues with the code.  We don't usually do pure code reviews (there's [a StackExchange site dedicated to that](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)).